# How can I understand an rpart plot without any splits?

Tags: r, decision-tree, party

I got some figures after I did decision tree model using part library.
This figures shows fundamental function of part library.

In these figures, I understand all excepts fourth kind of figure.
This figure don't have any powful feature. It does not show any information. How can I understand this figure?

[image: rpart visualizations]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

You are right. The fourth panel shows the visualization of a tree without any splits. Thus, in this case none of the available split variables improved the cost-complexity criterion of `rpart` and hence only the root node remains.

The visualization using the `partykit` package employs stacked bar plots for every terminal node in the trees (the default visualization for binary classification in the package). Thus, there is only a single stacked bar in case of a root node only.